# How to do a .filter() in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

In the django orm I can do something like the following:

```
people = Person.objects.filter(first_name='david')
for person in people:
    print person.last_name
```

How would I do the equivalent in Java Hibernate's orm? So far, I've been able to do a single get, but not a filter clause:

```
Person p = session.get(Person.class, "david");
```

What would be the correct way to do this though?

Comment: if You want programming in hibernate (personally, I suggesta JPA), read python book? Idioms in one language are not idioms in others

Comment: few 'active record' libraries exist in Java. But this totally diffrerent concept than JPA

Comment: @JacekCz ok -- then what would be the best way to accomplish the above? Do a HQL query?

Comment: You should use JPA (the standardized version, and now the officially preferred interface to Hibernate), and depending on your application, probably Spring Data, which will autogenerate queries for you.

Comment: Spring (since many years) is not required

Comment: @JacekCz Spring has never been required for Hibernate/JPA. Spring Data does, however, solve lots of problems for you automatically and conveniently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use native SQL

```
session.beginTransaction();
Person p = getSingleResult(session.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM People where name = 'david'",Person.class));
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

and the function getSingleResult would be somthing like this :

```
public static <T> T getSingleResult(TypedQuery<T> query) {
        query.setMaxResults(1);
        List<T> list = query.getResultList();
        if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return list.get(0);
    }
```

you can get a list like this :

```
List<Person> list = session
    .createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM People", Person.class)
    .getResultList();
```

Answer (score -2):

There are several approaches to do this so here goes:

- Lazy way - possibly bad if you have a tons of data is to just load up
  the whole list of persons, stream it and apply a filter to it to
  filter out objects not matching the given first name.
- Use a HQL query (Hibernate Query Language) to create a select query
  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/chapters/query/hql/HQL.html
- Use Hibernate's Criteria API to achieve the above
  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/chapters/query/criteria/Criteria.html

Alternatively you can even use a native SQL query to do the above.

Comment: At the very least link to modern documentation. Hibernate 3.3 is 10 years old and doesn't support most of the best practices like pervasive generics.

Comment: @chrylis Updated the links, in way the whole point of linking him something was to provide him with the general idea.